# copy NSMutableArray atIndex (0) to string variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, copy, nsmutablearray

i have an array and i want to extract value of array at specific index
like:

```
NSString Val1 = Array1[index1];
```

array is NSMutableArray.

Comment: What type of values is in the array? NSSting/NSObject/int/double?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSString *stringToExtract = [arrayToExtractFrom objectAtIndex:0];
```